# Align header with content

Tags: javascript, html

I have created accordion in javascript. I would like accordion header(my header) and accordion content information (table) to be aligned in the center. However, I could not able to figure that out. [image]

```
 $.each(myData.offsetFormations, function(i,aut) {
            headerList = '<h3><ul><li contenteditable="true">'+
                '<text class="formationName">'+ aut.FormationName + '</text>'+
                ' | ' +
                '<text class="bitSize">'+this.BitSize.toFixed(2) + '</text>'+
                ' | ' +
                '<text class="bitType">'+this.BitType + '</text>'+
                '</li></ul></h3>';

            wellNameList = '<div><table>';

            $.each(myData.wellList, function(k,mano){
                if(aut.AssociatedwellList.some(function(w) { return w.WellName === mano.WellName; }))
                    {
                    wellNameList += '<td><div>'+ mano.WellName+'</div></td>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                 wellNameList += '<td style="color:gray;" ><div>'+ mano.WellName+'</div></td>';
                    }
                });

            wellNameList += '</table></div>';

            headerList += '<div>'+wellNameList +'</div>';
            $(headerList).appendTo('#accordion'); 
        });
```

jsfiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/31/

Comment: casillas. I added support for header alignment too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the accordian content, each table's parent div needs `width:100%;`, and each table wthin it needs `margin:0 auto;`

Div parent given class of table-parent and css added:

http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/33/

To do the header use this:

css:

`.ui-accordion-header ul {
    display:inline-block;
}`

```
function resizeHeader(){
    var h3Width = $('h3.ui-accordion-header').width();
    var ulWidth = $('h3.ui-accordion-header ul').width();

    var margin =  (h3Width - ulWidth)/2/2;
    $('h3.ui-accordion-header ul').css('margin-left',margin);
}

resizeHeader();

$(window).resize(function(){resizeHeader()});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/34/